# Finding coordinates of a point in a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have generated a scatter plot using python.

How to find out the coordinates of a point?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [min(max(L2.real, 0.2), 0.3) for L2 in L]      

y = [min(max(L2.imag, 0), 0.004) for L2 in L]

plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You could use `zip(x, y)` to get a list of all the x/y pairs.

Comment: yeah, x and y are the coordinates

Comment: Or do you want to select a point in the plot with your mouse and have the coordinates shown in the plot?

Answer (score 0):

the coordinates of the i-th point are `(x[i], y[i])`. Is that what you're asking?